# c++ files are not being compiled in eclipse android ndk project

Tags: c++, eclipse, android-ndk

I have a simple ndk test project in eclipse. I have instlled all ndk, jdk, android sdk, cygwin and eclipse cdt.

now my android.mk file points to main.cpp which it compiles:

```
#include "test.h"

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    test* x = new test();
    x->myTest();
}
```

but complains that:

```
C:\Development\Android\Test/jni/main.cpp:18: undefined reference to `test::test()'
C:\Development\Android\Test/jni/main.cpp:19: undefined reference to `test::myTest()'
```

even though I have an implementation of test.cpp which looks like the following:

```
#include "test.h"

test::test() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

test::~test() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

int test::myTest() {
    #error "this comes from test"
    return 5;
}
```

and the test.h file declares the function like this (the declaration is found, just that the c++ file is never compiled):

```
#ifndef TEST_H_
#define TEST_H_

class test {
public:
    test();
    virtual ~test();
    int myTest();
};

#endif
```

This is my Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := mylib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The #error in test.cpp is never seen by the compiler unless I specify the class test.cpp in my local source files in my Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp test.cpp
```

I have a big project with thousands of classes that I need to port to Android and I cannot specify each file there. What could I be missing to make the compiler work properly? How can I tell the compiler to automatically use all the classes in my jni folder? It is probably just a one liner in Android.mk or somewhere in the settings?

Comment: managed to do it with:
    **FILE_LIST := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*.cpp)** and 
    **LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)**

in the Android.mk file

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android.mk - how to do wildcard in source folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824980/android-mk-how-to-do-wildcard-in-source-folder)