# Android.mk - how to do wildcard in source folder

Tags: android-ndk, makefile

That's how i do wildcard in JNI folder

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := some_module_name
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(notdir $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*.cpp)) 
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Now i want to add new source folder to JNI - some_src with foo.cpp and bar.cpp

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := some_module_name
FOLDER_PREFIX = some_scr
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(notdir $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*.cpp)) $(FOLDER_PREFIX)/$(notdir $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(FOLDER_PREFIX)/*.cpp))
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

But this adds $(FOLDER_PREFIX) to bar.cpp only, foo.cpp gets stripped path (jni/foo.cpp) and not builds of course.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(addprefix $(FOLDER_PREFIX),$(notdir $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(FOLDER_PREFIX)/*.cpp))`
```

or maybe even *(do you really need to specify `FOLDER_PREFIX`?)*:

```
$(subst $(LOCAL_PATH)/,,$(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*/*.cpp)))
```

The second form allows for the following shortcut:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(subst $(LOCAL_PATH)/,,$(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*.cpp) $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*/*.cpp)))
```