# Undefined Extern Reference in Eclipse

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile some simple c++ code in Eclipse that compiles fine in Visual Studio.

I have the following files (renamed and simplified for clarity). Main.cpp has other boilerplate code in it for the main function and so forth, which I've omitted.

**Foo.h**

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H
extern Int foo;
#endif
```

**Foo.cpp**

```
Int foo = 0;
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "Foo.h"
void bar() {
    foo = 1;
}
```

When I try to compile this in Eclipse, I get the following error (omitted the long paths)

```
Main.o: in function bar():jni/Main.cpp:25: error: undefined reference to 'foo'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I hover my mouse over foo in Main.cpp, it shows the tooltip for it, and if I right click on it and select Open Declaration, it takes me to Foo.cpp and highlights the foo declaration. So it is clearly finding it, but failing to compile.

If I move the declaration to Main.cpp, like below, then it compiles fine.

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "Foo.h"
Int foo = 0;
void bar() {
    foo = 1;
}
```

So for some reason, Eclipse is not seeing the declaration when it is placed in a different cpp file to the one that is actually referencing it. Why is that, and how do I fix it? Unfortunately, moving the declaration to the Main.cpp is not possible as the extern needs to be accessed across a number of cpp files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that the content of Foo.cpp is not being linked into the executable (and possibly not compiled).

Comment: All three files are included in the Eclipse project and as I mentioned before, if I right click on foo in Main.cpp and select Open Declaration, Eclipse takes me to Foo.cpp and highlights the foo declaration. Is there anything special I need to do to ensure a file is being compiled and linked in?

Comment: Try doing 'Clean Project' then 'Build Project' (both in the context menu when you right-click on the project in the C++ package explorer).  Then look at the console window - does it show both CPP files being compiled with g++?

Comment: (Or can you post the output in the console window?)

Comment: Looks like you are right. After checking the Console output carefully, I found no mention of the other cpp files. Just the Main.cpp file. You gave me a better idea of what to Google for and I came across [this post on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495993/c-files-are-not-being-compiled-in-eclipse-android-ndk-project), which has solved the problem. Thanks for your help.